# Foopicker popup is hidden when placed at bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am using jquery foopicker (date picker) libray. problem is when the text box is at the bottom of the page, it hides some part of the popup. i cannot even inspect it from developer tools. any help would be appreciable.
using below method to initialize

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="date">
```

**JS:**

```
var foopicker = new FooPicker({
       id: 'date',
       dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
 });
```

Comment: Can you add minimal working code ?

Comment: i have already added the code which is used to make date picker